# Check if string is null without erroring in c#

Tags: c#

In the line 3 Im getting   null exception. 'Discription' is a string were value sometimes is null. what check I can do before it goes to - (!Discription.ToLower().StartsWith("da") and throws error? Or how do I make null value acceptable?

```
private void FindBook(a, b)
{
    if (discription == null && (!Discription.ToLower().StartsWith("da")))  //getting 'Can't be NULL' exception here.How do approach this issue? How do I fix this?
    {
        IsInLibrary = false;
    }
    else
    {
        IsInLibrary = true;
    }
}

public string Discription
{
    get
    {
        return _discription;
    }

    set
    {
        _discription = value;

        if (value != null && (value.ToLower().StartsWith("da"))) //it is working here 
        {
            IsInLibrary = true;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("Discription");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please [edit] your question to select the correct language tag.

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(discription))`

Comment: Your 1st and 2nd checks for `null` are *not the same*, the 1st is wrong, the 2nd is correct as you already found (where it says `//it is working here`). Just compare them character by character...

Comment: You have `discription`, `Discription` and `_discription` do you need all 3?

Comment: this is if it is not null but I need it for null. after I need to do check for (!Discription.ToLower().StartsWith("da"))) which is erroring because it is null. If I take a way '!' it errors

Comment: @PeterB i know. In second one if it is not null it doesnt continue there for it doesnt throw error in next step. 1st one - it will be null therefore it continues and (!Discription.ToLower().StartsWith("da"))) throws exception that it's null. How do I fix that?

Comment: @tymtam - sorry mistake, discription and _discription is the same. It's one

Comment: Got a solution  - if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(discription)) || (!Discription.ToLower().StartsWith("da"))) thanks @shahkalpesh, it helped

Comment: "discription and _discription is the same" - did you mean there is a typo in your post? Then please fix that so we don't try to fix the wrong problem (you can [edit] your post)

Answer (score 1):

In Summary, your reversed the parts but you didn't change `&&` to `||`.

---

I think your question is about reversing logic from

```
if (x != null && x.ToLower().StartsWith("da"))
{
   y = true;
}
```

to

```
if (???)
{
   y = false;
}
```

## Option A. Reverse all of it

You can achieve it with ! around the whole content of if:

```
if (!(x != null && x.Something()))
{
  y = false;
}
```

## Option B. De Morgan's laws

[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) can be expressed as

- `not (A or B) = not A and not B`
- `not (A and B) = not A or not B.`

We want to use the 2nd law:

- `not (A and B) = not A or not B`

In our case:

1. `A => (x != null)`
2. `B => (x.ToLower().StartsWith("da"))`

Then:

not (`(x != null)` and `(x.ToLower().StartsWith("da"))`)

is equal to

not `(x != null)` or not `(x.ToLower().StartsWith("da")`

This can be simplified to:

`x == null` or `!x.ToLower().StartsWith("da")`

and in C#:

```
x == null || !x.ToLower().StartsWith("da")
```

Comment: OP: Mind that `x == null || !x.ToLower().StartsWith("da")` works, because the second clause won't be evaluated if the first one resolves to `true`.

Comment: @Fildor True and the same applies to `x != null && x.ToLower()...`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a nullref because you are checking whether the variable is null, not that it isnt.

Change:

`if (discription == null && (!Discription.ToLower().StartsWith("da")))`

To:

`if (discription != null && (!Discription.ToLower().StartsWith("da")))`

Aside from thise, people prefer to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)` to also check for empty or whitespace only strings, because often those are also invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)  && (value.ToLower().StartsWith("da")))
```

Comment: Or a more hackish short version: if ((value ?? "").ToLower().StartsWith("da"))